# File Scan a 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I am working on a problem in which I must file scan an input file and then assign the variables to i and j. The input file (input.txt) must look like this:

```
100 20
500 70
10 3
250 25
600 100
```

My code looks like this.

```
int i, j;
float table[5][5];
FILE * ifp = fopen("input.txt","r");
// initiliaze array
for (i=0; i <=1; i++)
    for (j=0;j<=4;j++)
        fscanf(ifp,"%f",&table[i][j]);
```

The problem I am having is that all of the values are being entered first into J 
sequentially.  I need the two columns to be split so that J reads in only the left line first.
So that `table[0][3]` Would represent `250` for example. And so that `table[1][0]` would
represent `20`.
Or
If easier. Put all of column `1` into `i` and column `2` into `j`. Let me know

```
           a[0]  a[1]
a[0][0]--> 100   20  <--a[1][0]
a[0][1]--> 500   70  <--a[1][1]
a[0][2]--> 10    3   <--a[1][2]
a[0][3]--> 250   25  <--a[1][3]
a[0][4]--> 600   100 <--a[1][4]
```

thanks. I have been struggling with this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to copy the columns of your file to the rows of the array

To do: Reverse the `for` loops

```
for (j=0;j<=4;j++)
    for (i=0; i <=1; i++)
```

that's all. And you will get the numbers in the order you want in your array

**BTW**

Use this instead

```
fscanf(ifp," %f",&table[i][j]);
```

Add space at the beginning of the string format of the scanf it should be `" %f"`

The added space will allow to catch newlines of your file

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things first:

- Did you see that your table dimensions were too big for what you wanted?
- Your nested `for` loop blocks aren't enclosed with braces.  If you have more than one statement to execute in a `for` loop, you won't execute them all unless they're enclosed in braces.

Now to the functionality of your program.

- You can read both values on a line with a single `fscanf` statement.  Your formatting string will be something like `"%f %f"` and you'll have two arguments following that.
- Are you *always* going to have an input file with no more than five lines?  If it can be longer, then you'll need to allocate memory as you go.

Hope that helps some.